# sql command which help me to group by or any other query

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
 select a.EmpId,AttenDate,status 
 from dbo.Attendance as a
      inner join dbo.employeemast as e
      on a.empid=e.empid
 where e.EmpWeekOfType='V'`
```

It gives me:

```
1500011 2014-08-31 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-01 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-02 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-03 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-04 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-05 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-06 00:00:00.000 P
1500011 2014-09-07 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-08 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-09 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-10 00:00:00.000 A
1500011 2014-09-11 00:00:00.000 A
```

I want to arrange the row with this format:

```
150011 | 2014-08-31 00:00:00.000|2014-09-01 00:00:00.000|2014-09-02 00:00:00.000.... 
                    A           |         A ........
```

Please suggest me a query??

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do. Also, it is helpful if you provide your tables' schema.

Comment: i want one time 'empid' relevant date with this row...

Comment: I think you wanted to write above this instead : `select a.EmpId,a.AttenDate,a.status ` ?

Comment: Which dbs are you using (postgre, mysql, ...)

Comment: if you are using ms sql server try using `for xml`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to convert a row based format (which is what RDBMS and SQL use) into a column based one?

This is not possible (with the standard SQL - maybe there are vendor specific extensions which would make it easier, but you didn't specify ans vendor). The reason, this isn't possible, is in the nature of RDBMS and SQL, where columns needs to be well defined, while the number of rows depends on the data.

Also you are trying to store different data types in one column for each row. Instead take the SQL output and transform it into what ever you need with a programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to come at least close to your goal would be to use arrays (at least in Postgre):

```
SELECT a.EmpId, array_agg(AttenDate), array_agg(status)
FROM dbo.Attendance AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.employeemast AS e
    ON a.empid=e.empid
WHERE e.EmpWeekOfType='V'
GROUP BY a.EmpId;
```

Sorry but dont know any similar for MS-SQL or MySQL. However, as peter said, getting the output exactly as you want to is not really possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(MAX)
 select @Temp=ISNULL(@Temp+' | ','')+CAST(a.EmpId  AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(AttenDate AS VARCHAR)+' '+[status]
 from dbo.Attendance as a
      inner join dbo.employeemast as e
      on a.empid=e.empid
 where e.EmpWeekOfType='V'
 SELECT @Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, this code is in MS SQL SERVER :

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @Columns = Stuff((SELECT ',' + '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), AttenDate, 121)
                                + ']'
                         FROM   Attendance s
                         WHERE  s.empid = t.empid
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM   Attendance AS t
GROUP  BY t.empid


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)= 'select [empid],' + @Columns
  + ' from Attendance pivot
(max(stus)
FOR AttenDate in(' + @Columns + ')
)as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql
```

**[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0d27/3)**

and with your query, this will be like :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Attendance',N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Attendance

SELECT a.EmpId,
       AttenDate,
       status
INTO   #Attendance
FROM   dbo.Attendance AS a
       INNER JOIN dbo.employeemast AS e
               ON a.empid = e.empid
WHERE  e.EmpWeekOfType = 'V' 

DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @Columns = Stuff((SELECT ',' + '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), AttenDate, 121)
                                + ']'
                         FROM   #Attendance s
                         WHERE  s.empid = t.empid
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM   #Attendance AS t
GROUP  BY t.empid


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)= 'select [empid],' + @Columns
  + ' from #Attendance pivot
(max(stus)
FOR AttenDate in(' + @Columns + ')
)as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql
```

I took reference from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2e2980dc-fd69-436c-87f8-3f42517a87c7/dynamically-converting-rows-into-columns-when-rows-are-not-fixed?forum=transactsql).

Answer (score 0):

try using cursor to get each row , from the row get empid and append to a variable(empid once and consecutive row datetime field until there is a change in empid). store the variable in temp table . perform this with every row and append data to variable until there is change in employeeid . finally select from temp table..... An approach to get your result .